# Custom Field Plugin With Image Field

Tags: 8, entities

I have been working on a custom field plugin with which the aim is to create a custom field to be used for content and will consist of a **link field** and a **file field** through which a thumb image is to be uploaded. I'm ok with the first part is i.e. the link field for which I have declared a **uri data definition** with a **varchar storage schema** and a **url type** for the form element. But I cannot (based on the available documentation) figure out the proper way to manage the **file field**. I have used a **managed_field type** as for the form element but cannot figure out what is the correct **datatype** and **storage schema** to use.

Edit: The documentation I have found deals with three parts,

1. The field class where the propertyDefinitions method is overridden and the properties are defined (ex. $properties['link'] = DataDefinition::create('uri')->setLabel(t('Video Link'));)
2. Also in the field class where the schema method is overridden and the storage properties are defined (ex. $columns['link'] = [ 'type' => 'varchar', 'length' => 255, ];)
3. the widget class where the formElement method is overridden to define the input form (ex. $element['link'] = [
           '#type' => 'url',
           '#title' => t('Link'),
           '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]->link) ? $items[$delta]->link : null,
           '#empty_value' => '',
           '#placeholder' => t('Insert a url'),
       ];)

what should the equivalent parts for an image/file field property be defined?

any input would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: "To me, your new field is basically a image field with an extra link field", slightly modified quote from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38996037/drupal-8-field-plugin-with-field-type-managed-file/39036241#39036241

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why don't you try the [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) module? This looks like a simple combination existing of field types, which is exactly Paragraphs' point.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood correctly:

```
FileItem.php
```

Have a look at `public static function defaultStorageSettings()` and `public static function schema(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition)`

Comment: Hi Dumitru, do you mean that I should be extending the FileItem instead of the  FieldItemBase class? I have edited my initial question in order to give more details  thanks for your answer

Comment: Considering the fact that you want to bundle the file field and the link field, perhaps you should consider the Paragraphs module which @Hudri mentioned, unless you need it done custom. If you need it to be custom-made, then think about providing a field which actually contains both of the fields. This would mean having code like `$properties['CUSTOM_LINK_FIELD']['link'] = DataDefinition::create('uri')->setLabel(t('Video Link'));`.